# How to remove white border from my android web page?

Tags: android, css

I am trying to make an android web application. MY first page- index.html contains just a list :

```
<body>
    <ul>
    <li>French  </li>
    <li>English </li>
    <li>Spanish </li>
    <li>Hindi   </li>
    <li>Urdu    </li>
    <li>Bengali </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

I used the following style :

```
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);  
}
html
{
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.9;
     border-style : none;
    width:100%;
    }

li
{

    height:10%;
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
}
```

but when i run my application, it shows a thick white border. How can I remove this border?
Here is my Activity class code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wb);
        WebSettings webSettigs= wv.getSettings();
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems this is a web page only. What about Android codes ?

Comment: But i guess, it has to do with CSS part. I am not sure about it.

Comment: Add body { margin:0; }

Comment: If that does not solve the problem, please show a UI screen!

Comment: I did that Eric and Stephane. It didnt work. I am unable to share my UI screen here.